# Store the digital data from analog to digital converter ADC(0804) in 8051

Tags: c, 8051, digital, adc

how can I store digital data from analog to digital converter ADC(0804) in 8051 for transmission purposes?

This help means a lot to me.
Any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Google is your friend - note that SO is not a programming tutorial service

Comment: Asked like this this question is too simple. You would store the value inside some variable and use the value of this variable later to send it over serial link as an example. Provide some minimal code sample so that we can help you

Comment: @NGI, I suppose there will be more issues, e.g. calibration, sampling and mean / average calculus, reference voltage fluctuation and other interesting moments. It's more about mathematics than programming.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should investigate and understand the ADC0804 datasheet to how an ADC works. However, I will add a simple ADC code in 8051 assembly, I believe you can write the c code by understanding the assembly code. I am not doing this just for you, also for the other people who don't know ADC and come here to search for it.

Take some time and give some effort to make your work useful. It has no meaning if you just copy it from somewhere, try to learn it. Then you will see the beautiful side of understanding.

```
RD BIT P2.5
WR BIT P2.6
INTR BIT P2.7
DATA EQU P1
MOV P1,#0FFh
SETB INTR
BACK: CLR WR
SETB WR
HERE: JB INTR,HERE
CLR RD
MOV A,DATA
SETB RD
SJMP BACK
```

PS: I am adding two diagrams from the datasheet, check them to understand how the ADC basically works.
[ADC1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sF2gu.png) [ADC2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2WJw.png)

Also, I am suggesting you to ask microprocessor related questions to the electrical engineering section. It's mostly their topic, so they return faster.